# php-cgi POST request turns into GET request for no reason

Tags: c#, php, post, webserver, cgi

I'm developping a windows web server in php and I want to use php-cgi.
It works well but I'm having problems with GET and POST request. When I set enviroment variable "REQUEST_METHOD" to "POST", I don't get anything in the $_POST variable but I get the content in $_GET :/ It doesn't make ANY sense...

Here is my code:

```
Process php = new Process();
php.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/PHP-7.1/php-cgi.exe";
php.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
php.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"] = "CGI/1.1";
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] = page;
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "POST";
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["REDIRECT_STATUS"] = "true";
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] = "HTTP/1.1";
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = ServerVersion;
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1";
//php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["CONTENT_LENGTH"] = "3"; // Causes crash
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "text/html";
String QueryString = "";
if (request.GET_Variables.Count() > 0)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (String variable in request.GET_Variables)
    {
        QueryString += variable + "=" + request.GET_Values[i];
        i++;
        if (i != request.GET_Variables.Count())
        {
            QueryString += "&";
        }
    }
}
php.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["QUERY_STRING"] = QueryString;
php.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f \"" + page + "\"";
Console.WriteLine("php-cgi.exe " + php.StartInfo.Arguments); // Debug
php.Start();
```

For example, If:

```
QUERY_STRING="fox=brown&dog=lazy"
```

The var_dump(); will look like this:

```
GET: array(2) { ["fox"]=> string(5) "brown" ["dog"]=> string(4) "lazy" }
POST: array(0) { }
```

I hope someone can help me, have a nice day !

Comment: I'm guessing here but ordinarily, POST values are not supplied in the query string but in the request body. Could that be what's confusing PHP into filling `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) I'm quit a noob, so I don't don't know what is the request body :/ is it thye arguments ? like this ?:
php-cgi.exe -f "D:\www\_w32n\get.php" fox=brown&dog=lazy

Comment: Like I said, I'm guessing. But I've read some pages about not calling `php.Start()` but opening a pipe with popen, then writing the request body to it.